# Angular 7 - How to separate files in different directories

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

I am configuring my Angular 7 application to production and trying to organise files in different directories.

angular.json

```
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/appname-ui",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/js/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/js/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css",
                            "src/appname-theme.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    },
```

Currently my directory looks like this:

```
├── dist
|   ├── <appname>
|   |   ├── assets
|   |   |   ├── icons
|   |   |   ├── images

|   |   |   index.html
|   |   |   *.js (bundled files: runtime.js, polyfills.js, vendor.js, main.js)
|   |   |   *.map
|   |   |   style.css
|   |   |   *.woff, *.woff2, *.tff, *.eot
```

With the compilation, bundled javascript files are generated on the root directory along with font files that are copied to the root directory as well

I would like to:

1. Specify a different directory to bundled js files
2. Specify a different directory to font files.
   (if it has to be the same directory of the js files no problem, but nice to be different)

The structure would looks like this:

```
├── dist
|   ├── <appname>
|   |   ├── assets
|   |   |   ├── icons
|   |   |   ├── images

|   |   |   index.html
|   |   |   style.css

|   |   ├── libs
|   |   |   |   *.js
|   |   |   |   *.map

|   |   ├── fonts
|   |   |   *.woff, *.woff2, *.tff, *.eot
```

Is it possible to achieve this? If yes how?

Thank you very much for your help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not supported officially but you can use ,

```
--baseHref=baseHref      Base url for the application being built.

--deployUrl=deployUrl    URL where files will be deployed.

--outputPath=outputPath  path for the new output directory
```

By combining them you can move the js/map/index.html files to specific location  and update the baseHref and url in index.html.

More on,

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10171

Comment: Thank you. This configurations is just specifying what should be included on the build. Actually "src/libs" does not exist. I just would like to copy to a specific directory the generated files (runtime.js, polyfills.js, vendor.js, main.js)

Comment: unfortunately your suggestion does not work, actually it gives a compilation error because the src/libs directory does not exists.

Comment: Its getting closer. --deployUrl="/js/" indicates the path to those generated files to be used on the index.html, but it does not created the directory it self or even copy the files there. Is there a way to copy them?

Comment: Use some scripts to do that , that's how we do with our CI/CD

Answer (score -1):

Based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration), you just need to update your angular.json file to change assets directory.

Something like:

```
"assets": [{ "glob": "sitemap.xml", "input": "src/assets/", "output": "/" }],
```

And to change bundle js path you need to specify new path at time of build i.e. `ng build --prod --outputPath=NEW_PATH` -- documentations - [Link](https://angular.io/cli/build) otherwise you just need to update js path in index.html

Comment: my problem is not with the assets. Everything in the assets directory is going to be copied. (actually i was able to fix the redundant fonts being copied. they should not be part of assets.) My problem is actually with the generated files. They are always copied to the root directory

Comment: okay so mainly you need to specify bundle files (polyfills, main, etc.) location. Right?

Comment: exactly, sorry if i did not express properly